# How to get data from other website using php?

Tags: php, web-scraping

This is my first question on this site, sorry if it is not clear enough.

So my problem is that, i would like to get all of the product IDs from a webshop, that has no API.
A product id looks like: xy-000000

I know that I need a webscraper, but the problem is that i don’t know how to find a specific word like xy- 000000 with it. I tried many web-scrapers, but the only thing that i could find with them is html tags like the title or keywords.

I searched a lot for it on google, and found some web scrapers, bat they are not working fine for me.

As i mentioned, i would like to get all of the product IDs from a different webshop using php, for finding some products that i am not selling. (My webshop has the same product IDs as the other.)

Can anyone please help me find a php script that is similar to what i need?

So this is the code that i am trying to use:

```
 <?php
    $data = file_get_contents('https://www.mesemix.hu/hu/superman-ruhanemuk/11292-szuperhosoek-mintas-zokni.html');

    error_reporting(0);

    preg_match('/<title>([^<]+)<\/title>/i', $data, $matches);
    $title = $matches[1];

    preg_match('/[0-9]{6}/', $data, $matches);
    $number = $matches[1];

    preg_match('/<img[^>]*src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"][^>]*>/i', $data, $matches);
    $img = $matches[1];

    echo $title."<br>\n";
    echo $img."<br>\n";
    echo $number;
    echo $data;
    ?>
```

The problem is that i can not find the 6 digit number with it. ($number)

In the webshop's source code it looks like this:

var productReference = 'SP- 418070';

If there is anything wrong with my question please let me know.

Comment: What you're attempting to build is a web-scraper.  You should put forth an honest attempt at solving the problem and outlining what you've tried (provide actual code you're trying to use).  It sounds like you might just need to hire a developer to do it for you, because your question is essentially asking someone to do all the work.

Comment: try somthing on your own like scrapper or APIs if they are providing, and then ask for help. No one here will give readymade code here. Or get paid help from [codementor](https://www.codementor.io/shyammakwana)

Comment: You are right that looks like i am trying to hire a developer to do it for me, i found many web scrapers the problem is that all of them is getting the title or the keywords or an image url, which is not bad, but i don’t know how to find the actual product IDs. The webshop is a javascript generated website an i am not able to find anything in it.

Answer (score 3):

The Term you are looking for is "Web-Scraper"

You can do it in a couple of different ways.

One of these 2 PHP libraries

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Or

https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte

Both are very simple to use there are documentations for both of them

The way they work are just like jQuery (javascript) you target the data that you need to get by the CSS selectors